# css forced-color-adjust property don't work in facebook browser in-app, how solve?

Tags: html, css, facebook, browser, in-app

looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/forced-color-adjust i have this code HTML in `test.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>   
    <br>
    <div class="box forced">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>       
</body>
</html>
```

and this CSS in `style.css` file:

```
.box {
  border: 5px solid grey;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-color: black;
}

@media (forced-colors: active) {
  .forced {
    forced-color-adjust: none;
  }
}
```

Both files in same directory. CSS is detected. Well, i upload this two files in remote and for test i make a post in facebook.
When i click in this post, i open test.html inside **FACEBOOK BROWSER IN-APP** and display in darkmode in both cases text in white.
The box with css class `.forced` should be allow to display text in black color but so not is!
In general i have a background color like near yellow and to have forced black color in white not help if user try to read.
So i ask, as i can solve this problem?
Thanks very much.

Comment: [it has really poor browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=forced-color-adjust). what browser are you using?

Comment: In general i not have problem with all others browser. Need only solve with FACEBOOK BROWSER IN-APP which in dark mode change black color in white color. I want deny which facebook do it becouse with background (like something as yellow) having white color is hard to read for users.

Answer (score 1):

just want communicate which i have solved the problem with:

```
:root {
     color-scheme: light only;
}
```

Thanks again.